# Use Cheerio to unbox certain elements

Tags: html, cheerio

Let’s say, I have an HTML like:

```
<p><a href=“foo”>bar</a></p>
```

Note this is a very simple example, actual documents could be way more complex.

I’d like to unbox all `a` elements, i.e. replace them with their inner HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`replaceWith`](https://cheerio.js.org/#replacewith-content-) to replace all the `a` tags with its inner html.

```js
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const $ = cheerio.load('<p><a href=“foo”>bar</a></p>')

$('a').each((i, el) => {
  const $el = $(el);
  $el.replaceWith($el.html());
})

console.log($.html());
```

https://repl.it/@moshfeu/CumbersomeNanoDatum